# jquery 1.4.4 check checkbox if checked returns true every time

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am using jquery 1.4.4 and trinying to check if this checkbox is checked

```
<input type="checkbox" style="float:right" checked="" id="mainBond">
```

I tried several techniques but non of them worked and I get 'true' every time

```
var chkd  = ($('#mainBond:checked').val()==undefined) ? 0 :1;
var chkd  = $('#mainBond').is(':checked');
var chkd  = $('#mainBond').attr('checked');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting true, because you had placed checked="" there

```
checked=""
```

if you removed that, it will show you false.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#mainBond').is(':checked')` works in jQuery 1.4.4: http://jsfiddle.net/LBKPG/ http://jsfiddle.net/LBKPG/1/

```
<input type="checkbox" style="float:right" checked id="mainBond"> This one is true
<input type="checkbox" style="float:right" id="mainBond2"> This one is false
​
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because it is checked. The value of the `checked` attribute is not important. As soon as it's present the box will be checked.

Just remove the attribute if you don't want it to be checked

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write your input line properly. It should have been:
`<input type="checkbox" style="float:right" checked id="mainBond">`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is working even in 1.4.4. Here is an example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/urX3z/ which... works, try clicking the checkbox and wait for 3 seconds to see you get true, uncheck it and you will get false.

EDIT: didn't save the example. wrong link.